# I want help related to update function of dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well I want to return an updated dictionary dependent on if else conditional statement through a function. But every time It returns null value instead of updated value. I wanted to update dictionary and return it on single line. Why the update function assign null value instead of updated values

```
def to_json(condition=True):
    ls = ["abc", "xyz", "123"]
    dis = {
        "id": 123,
        "value": "1122"
    }
    if condition is False:
        return dis
    else:
        return dis.update({"Key": ls})


print(to_json())
```

output:
None

instead of: 
{'id': 123, 'value': '1122', 'Key': ['abc', 'xyz', '123']}

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have some style tips: use `if not condition:` in place of `if condition is False:`, and use `dis["Key"] = ls` in place of `dis.update({"Key": ls})`.

Answer (score 2):

The `update()` function returns nothing, so by returning the call to update the dict, you will always receive `None`

If you make the udpate to the dict before the return statement, *then* return the dict, you should see your results.

```
def to_json(condition=True):
    ls = ["abc", "xyz", "123"]
    dis = {
        "id": 123,
        "value": "1122"
    }
    if condition is False:
        return dis
    else:
        dis.update({"Key": ls})
        return dis


print(to_json())
```

Comment: Thanks Matt B ! I have find the answer "The .update() method alters the dictionary in place and returns None. The dictionary itself is altered, no altered dictionary needs to be returned."